# My directive creates a <select> template. How can I make it call a function with the selected value when it changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive. Here is the simplified version with just the part that does not work:

```
app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngChange: "&",
            ngModel: "=",
            options: "="
        },
        template: '<select ng-change="ngChange()" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options">',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

When I call this function like this:

```
<div admin-select
   ng-change="ctrl.typeChanged()"
   ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.examTypeId"
   options="ctrl.examType.dataPlus"></div>
```

How can I get the current value of the model and supply it into the ctrl.typeChanged() function?

I already tried this:

```
typeChanged = function () {
   alert(self.configService.admin.examTypeId)
};
```

However it does not give the value that is **just selected**. It always alerts the previous value selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `select` will be stored in the scope variable that you set in its own `ng-Model`. Now, if what you want is to have a function that you want to get triggered when the value changes, just define that function in the controller of your directive, and call it from the `ng-change` of the `select`.

For example:

```
        template: '<select ng-change="myChangeFunct()" ng-model="mySelectVal" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options">',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
             $scope.myChangeFunct = function(){ alert($scope.mySelectVal); };
        }
```

**I would be a bit careful with the name of the attributes that you are using for your directive because they could conflict with the angular js directives.**

Try with this in your directive definition:

```
app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            adminChange: "&",
            adminModel: "=",
            adminOptions: "="
        },
        template: '<select ng-change="adminChange()" ng-model="adminModel" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in adminOptions">',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        }
    };
});
```

And this when you instantiate it:

```
<div admin-select
   admin-change="ctrl.typeChanged()"
   admin-model="ctrl.configService.admin.examTypeId"
   admin-options="ctrl.examType.dataPlus"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is a big help to me in understanding what my problem is. I have one problem however. The change function can be different. Is there a way I could pass the name of this function into my directive or make it trigger a function in the parent scope but with the $scope.mySelectVal?  I am sorry if this sounds confusing. I just need the directive to be able to handle calls to different functions to do things. Thanks for your advice so far.

Comment: @SamanthaJ absolutely, actually if that's the case, your code was correct for the "ng-change". Because you are defining a directive with an isolated scope, so if you want to pass a function that's the right way to do it, but I would use another name, since ngChage could be a reserved key-word for angularjs.

Comment: @SamanthaJ I just updated the answer, I hope that that helps.